# I can't create a virtual environment set only to python3 in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv

When I want to create a virtual environment with python3 (well python3.6 to be more precise) it keeps installing both python version even when I explicitly stated for it not to.

I used the command:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 trydjango/
```

Output:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/oren/Dev/Python- 
Dev/trydjango/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /home/oren/Dev/Python- 
Dev/trydjango/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

When I look at the bin directory, I expected only python3.6 installed but this is the output:

```
activate       activate.ps1      easy_install      pip3    python3        
wheel
activate.csh   activate_this.py  easy_install-3.6  pip3.6  python3.6
activate.fish  activate.xsh      pip               python  python-config
```

Comment: Look carefully, those are symlinks.. try `ls -l trydjango/bin`

Comment: Thank you, I uninstalled virtualenv with pip and pip3 because I used both pip and pip3 for it. So I only installed it with pip3.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I used both 
pip install virtualenv and pip3 install virtualenv. I uninstalled both and only used pip3 install virtualenv. So now it only uses python3.

Comment: There's no need to install virtualenv in python3. It already has a built-in module for that matter. Try `python3 -m venv myvenv-name`

Answer (score 0):

In the bin folder, both `python` and `python3` are just symbolic links to `python3.6`. This is for convenience so you don't have to always type `python3.6`.

You can test this by using `python --version` to see what version actually runs.